Theme Not Loading on Page Load but Works on Radio Button Selection
I'm purely a beginner and this is for my project in  one of my majors. I'm trying to implement a theme-switching feature on one of my subpages (Article1.html) using JavaScript, where users can select themes (Dark Modern, Pink Pastel, Windows XP) via radio buttons in a pop-up menu. The theme should load immediately when the page loads if it was previously saved, but it only loads after selecting a theme from the menu. I can't see any css and it's just plain html when I open the index.html (parent page/home).
Expected Behavior: The saved theme should be applied immediately on page load.
Actual Behavior: The theme only loads after selecting a theme from the menu.
Here's what I have:

JavaScript function (setTheme) that changes the CSS file, and header image based on the selected theme.
Radio button listeners that call setTheme and save the selection to localStorage when a theme is chosen.
Page load function that retrieves the saved theme from localStorage and applies it via setTheme, which I expect to apply the theme immediately on load.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.
Code for HTML:
<!--Control Panel-->
        <div class="controlPanel">
            <button class="arrangement" onclick="openMenu('arrangementMenu')">Arrangement</button>
            <button class="order" onclick="openMenu('orderMenu')">Order</button>
            <button class="themes" onclick="openMenu('themesMenu')">Themes</button>
        </div> <!--controlPanel-->

        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="overlay" id="overlay" onclick="closeMenu()"></div>

                <!-- Arrangement Menu -->
                <div id="arrangementMenu" class="popupMenu">
                    <button class="closeBtn" onclick="closeMenu()">X</button>
                    <h3>Arrangement</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="notAvailable">
                        <p>This feature is not available for this page.</p>
                        <p>Go <a href="../index.html">back to home.</a></p> 
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- arrangementMenu -->

                <div id="orderMenu" class="popupMenu">
                    <button class="closeBtn" onclick="closeMenu()">X</button>
                    <h3>Order</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="notAvailable">
                        <p>This feature is not available for this page.</p>
                        <p>Go <a href="../index.html">back to home.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- orderMenu -->
                
                <!-- Themes Menu -->
                <div id="themesMenu" class="popupMenu">
                    <button class="closeBtn" onclick="closeMenu()">X</button>
                    <h3>Theme:</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="radio-group">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="theme" value="astyle - dark modern.css" onclick="setTheme('astyle - dark modern.css')">Dark Modern</label>
                        <hr>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="theme" value="astyle - pink pastel.css" onclick="setTheme('astyle - pink pastel.css')">Pink Pastel</label>
                        <hr>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="theme" value="astyle - windows xp.css" onclick="setTheme('astyle - windows xp.css')">Windows XP</label>
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="saveTheme()" class="closeBtn">OK</button>
                </div> <!-- themesMenu -->

Code for Javascript:
// Function to open a menu
function openMenu(menuId) {
    console.log("Opening menu:", menuId);
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelectorAll(".popupMenu").forEach(menu => {
        menu.style.display = "none";
    });
    // Takes the ID of menu and plugs in to this getElementById
    document.getElementById(menuId).style.display = "block";
}

// Function to close a menu
function closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelectorAll(".popupMenu").forEach(menu => {
        menu.style.display = "none";
    });
}

// Function to switch themes based on radio button selection and save to local storage
function setTheme(sheet) {
    var stylesheet = document.getElementById('articleTheme');
    stylesheet.setAttribute('href', sheet);
    localStorage.setItem('cssTemplate', sheet);

    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    
    if (sheet === "astyle - dark modern.css") {
        header.src = "../images/dark modern header.png";
    } else if (sheet === "astyle - pink pastel.css") {
        header.src = "../images/pink pastel header.gif";
    } else if (sheet === "astyle - windows xp.css") {
        header.src = "../images/windows xp header.gif";
    }    
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var themeStyle = localStorage.getItem('cssTemplate') || 'astyle - dark modern.css';
    setTheme(themeStyle);
});


You could start by adding a: "I don't recognize this sheet" alert in the setTheme(sheet) function, so that when it received a sheet name it doesn't know, it tell you so.

Is your element with the id of articleTheme loaded when you load the page? You do not show that part in your HTML. Do you get errors in the browser console?

hello welcome to stackoeverflow what is saveTheme() function?

@ErfanTa I scrapped the idea  forgot to remove it before pasting here.

@LajosArpad I put it as an id of my link when linking my default css stylesheet.

Thank you all for your help! I was able to just rename my files because my console says it can't find the specific file on a path.

@jentlechu is it working now?

To assist you with your question, i created this CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/7dx7hz?file=%2Findex.html%3A45%2C11. Take a look to see if it meets your needs.
Since you didn’t provide your CSS, I included only the HTML elements and three CSS files to represent the themes.

Hello, thank you so much for this. I'll see if I can work around on it.
